# osCommerce: Use persistent connection

Tags: settings, oscommerce, persistent-connection

I have here a osCommerce 2.2-MS2.  I had some settings before which were working fine. Now I changed the settings for the connection to the database (username, password, database, ...) but didn't noticed that the changes weren't saved. Now I want to check if my changes were successfull. I saw that there is a setting `use persistent connection` which is set to true. So I think he saves the old settings somewhere. How can I restart the connection to test if my new settings are OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is the same issue you had with your other OSCommerce related question where your configuration.php was not actually saved because of 444 permissions and you saw a modified version with your FileZilla local file?

Comment: Yeah, this seams possible. But it's quit a long time ago (so I can't exactly remember). Nevertheless, I'll close this question by selecting your answer.